# How to sync GIT and MySQL for application backup?

Tags: php, mysql, git, bash, yii2

How can I keep a application (Yii2/PHP) with a database (MySQL) in sync when restoring a backup? The application is versioned and tagged with GIT and the database is backuped using mysqldump every night. The Adminstrator should be able to restore any database backup made (using either a script or a button in the application).

Example: When restoring the database from a dump ten days ago this requires to checkout the appropriate code base from git (also from ten days ago).

Is this solved best

- using a bash-script for restoring or
- modifying the application to write GIT tags into the database or
- modifying GIT (hooks) to keep syncing or
- any other way?

Are there design patterns, scripts, Yii2-extensions, etc. out there to do this?

BTW: I don't want to include the database dumps in GIT since this explodes the space required by GIT.

Comment: Do you just want to match the timestamps? If that's the case, just check the timestamp of the git tag you're restoring from, then pick the dump from that night. Should be a trivial enough script.

Comment: No, I'd like to keep a GIT branch and a tag synced with the database. So maybe the branch and tag have to be stored in the database?

Comment: Well, why not? That's just a few bytes...

Comment: Alternatively you can have an external "receipt" with that info for each dump. Either case it's trivial.

Comment: ok, but how to keep the branch and tag updated in the database?

Comment: When you deploy a new version of your application? I'm not exactly sure about your situation and limitations. If the database is not easily updatable, then maybe the receipt approach (receipt created alongside each dump) is better.

Comment: What do you mean by"receipt", a bash-script hooked into git?

Comment: Just a plain text file with some metadata.